# Crear Archivo .d.ts

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, tailwind

Como estan?

Me pasa lo siguiente, vengo usando tailwind y daisyui para dar estilos a mi web. Y de un momento para otro la web dejo de traer esos estilos.

Cuando voy al config.js del tailwind me sale esto:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me dice que tengo que crear un de declaracion .d.ts que incluya "declare module 'daisyui';"

Alguno sabe o me podria guiar como hacer esto por favor?
Si no tengo que hacer todos los estilos desde 0 y llevaria un monton de tiempo.

Gracias!

Comment: `npm i --save-dev @types/daisyui`

Comment: ya lo intente pero me tira varios ERR 404 la consola

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Comment: posiblemente tengas una version de daisyui que esta usando ES6 para adelante y no los modulos de nodeJS, por lo que ese puede ser uno de los problemas.

Answer (score 1):

Este error sucede por que en typescript es necesario que todos los modulos tengan sus interfaces. Como intentaste instalar los @types de `daisyui` y no funcionó, la otra solución es crear un file llamado `module.d.ts` en tu carpeta `src`. Dentro de dicho file, debes escribir lo siguiente para indicarle al compilador que la librería no tiene interfaces:

```js
declare module 'daisyui';
```

Ahora si quieres definir las interfaces (ojo, NO es la implementación), puedes editar ese mismo archivo para añadírselas:

```js
declare module 'daisyui' {
    export function helloWorld (arg: string);
    export default class HelloWorld {
       constructor (arg: number)
       toBigint(a: number): BigInt
    }
};
```